# Javascript - get the form if of current control location

Tags: javascript

I have a form and it has 4 input elements. if the user enters just two entries and clicks anywhere on the screen (out the form)...i would like to save the details..it is like auto-save.

I have id of my form..i want to compare with form id of the current control on the screen..so that i can ssave the data if both form ids are different..

could you please tell me how can i get the form id of current control location on screen (some times the control could be outside the forms..in that case form id of current cotrol location would null)... but how can i determine that in javascript.

please suggest...

Many Thanks in advance,
Jack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting question.

Well, if you didn't think a second (as I admittedly did), you would just hook on the `blur` event of the HTML `<form>` element in question.

```
<form onblur="autosave(this)">
```

However, the HTML `<form>` element doesn't support that event. Too bad.

I then thought about jQuery's new 1.4 [`focusout()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event.

```
$('form').focusout(function() { autosave(this); });
```

Unfortunately that event get fired as well when you just jump (tab, click) to the next input field inside the same form. Not so nice, it'll probably be too expensive to autosave on every fieldjump. The same effect as with an `$(':input').blur(function() { autosave(this.form); });`.

I then tried the other way round using [`focusin()`](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/):

```
$('form').focusin(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focused');
});
$(':not(form)').focusin(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents('form.focused').length) {
        var form = $('form.focused').removeClass('focused');
        autosave(form);
    }
});
```

Strangely enough this works in IE only and not in the other browsers. It'll be another IE bug/quirk that `focus` is supported by all elements other than input elements.

Your best bet will probably be hooking on the [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event instead.

```
$('form').focusin(function() {
    $(this).addClass('focused');
});
$(':not(form)').click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).parents('form.focused').length) {
        var form = $('form.focused').removeClass('focused');
        autosave(form);
    }
});
```

This works fine. You can find here a [live demo](http://jsbin.com/ubefe3).

<sub>Note that I don't mean to push you jQuery (a JS library which insanely eases HTML DOM traversion and manipulation) through your throat or so, but I don't see nice ways in *plain* JavaScript to achieve this without writing 10 times as much as code here.</sub>

Comment: Excellent.. thank you very much for thsi... i am using ibm jsf framework..can i control this by giving id to my form ( i can have multiple forms in my page in my scenario an i don't want to save other form data - i.e input fields).

Comment: also, in my form i can have read-only data..not just input fields..i want to save both inpu fields and read-only data..could you please suggest me how i can do this...please let me know how to retrieve these auto submitted form data on server-side...i think request.getparameter may work...but i am using jsf (my page binds to a backing bean)..please suggest...sorry for mutiple questions.. this is bit complicated area to me..

Comment: You can use `$('#formId')` to select the form by ID. But since you're using JSF (you should really have mentioned that in the beginning), then it will be harder to get it all seamlessly to work. You should be either looking for a JSF component library with ajaxical powers or homegrow a servlet which listens on ajaxical requests and gets the JSF session scoped bean as attribute from the session.

Comment: oh...sorry, it was my mistake..

i don't need this to work seamlessly..i want to click a button when the control is out of the form...that will do for me..just wondering, how it works with jquesry..

Comment: Hi BalusC,

I have got this working by changing like this..
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $('form').focusin(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('focused');
                });
                $(':not(form)').bind('click', function(e) {
                    if (!$(e.target).parents('form.focused').length) {
                        document.getElementById("saveCustomerDetails").click();     
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

Comment: but i have two form..the top form has got number of action buttons...the bottom form needs my required functionality...if i click anywhere outside the bottom form, i could click my action using
document.getElementById("saveCustomerDetails").click();    

but if i click on an action in top form, the bottom action is not getting triggered...is this becoz both form start with <form element..can i avoid this by using form ids approach? please recommend...